# Python Crash Course : Using int() to accept numerical input

Tags: python

i am new to programming. According to my book, this code should get an error.

```
>>> age = input("How old are you? ")
How old are you? 21 
>>> age >= 18
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
vTypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()
```

In Sublime i saved a .py file:[This is my .py file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbCch.png)

Then , in the terminal when i tried running it. It did not give me an error. 
First time , i ran it by entering the age 21 without the quots , it returned True.
Then , i entered 17 , it returned False.

**Firstly , How does my computer know that they are integers? I did not enter age=int(age).**

Secondly when i input  "21", its returning True. No error. Why is that happening?

**How is it comparing a string and an integer?**
and when i input "17" as my age, it returned True again . **Why is that happening?

It is not only comparing a sting and an integer but giving the wrong answer also this time.**

[This is the screenshot of my terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH1U4.png)

[image: This is the respective terminal window after i installed python 3] [image: This is my new .py file after installing python 3.]

Comment: You are using python2 and the book is using python3, input in python 2 is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4915366/1222951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Python 2 and the book author is using Python 3.

In Python 2 `input` tries to evaluate the entered value, so the string `'21'` actually becomes `21` as an `int`.

As @Siddharth pointed out in the comments, `str > int` will always evaluate to `True` in Python 2. In Python 3 it will raise the error that is mentioned in the book.

Comment: In python 2 the interpreter does not throw an error in case of a string to int comparison instead always consider string to have a higher value than int.

Comment: @DeepSpace i entered raw_input instead of input. and saved the file. It is still not giving any error when i enter 21 :/ in the terminal.

Comment: @RishabhChopra As Siddharth pointed out, `str > int` will always evaluate  to `True` in Python 2. In Python 3 it will raise the error that is mentioned in the book.

Comment: @RishabhChopra, if the book is using python3 I would recommend you do the same

Comment: Everybody, thanks for the help . I will install python 3 and get back to you.

Comment: As advised i installed python 3.  But there is still no change. I see no error. I see exactly the same behaviour as to what i saw with python2. Please help me with this.

Comment: @RishabhChopra Seems like the code is still being run by the Python 2 interperter. Verify that by adding `import sys; print(sys.version_info)`.

Comment: @DeepSpace In sublime , when i entered import sys; print(sys.version_info) in an empty .py file: It returned : sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)